# how to return the number of times Singleton accessed getInstance()?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I want to use a private int type accessCount() to return the times of Singleton has been accessed via the getInstance() method, but always get error. Here's my two piece of code:

**ExampleSingleton.java**

```
public class ExampleSingleton {
  private int accessCount;
  private static ExampleSingleton instance = new ExampleSingleton();
  private ExampleSingleton() {
    System.out.println("I, the ExampleSingleton, am being created");
   }
  public static ExampleSingleton getInstance() {
    System.out.println("The sole instance of ExampleSingleton is being retrieved")
    
  }

}
```

**ExampleTest.java**

```
public class ExampleTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExampleSingleton s = ExampleSingleton.getInstance();
    System.out.println("The ExampleSingleton has been "
    + "accessed via the getInstance() method "
    + s.accessCount()
    + " time(s)");
    s = ExampleSingleton.getInstance();
    System.out.println("The ExampleSingleton has been "
    + "accessed via the getInstance() method "
    + s.accessCount()
    + " time(s)");
  }
}
```

So I can get the following output
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKjXC.png)

Comment: if it's _really_ a `Singleton`, then why count?

Comment: You know you never increment `accessCount` right? It should be static too.

Comment: I know it's a static variable, how can I increment the accesscount?

Comment: the getInstance is static but if I add the accessCount++, the error shows I reference unstatic from static. And if I make the accessCount as static int, the error shows cant find s.accessCount()

Comment: Make your `accessCount` variable static by adding the keyword, also will need to initialize it to 0: `private static int accessCount = 0;`

Comment: Then add the `accessCount++` on the `getInstance()` right? But then error shows in the `s.accessCount()`

Comment: s.accessCount() shows error because there is no method accessCount() in ExampleSingleton class. do you want to create one? or should it be a method called getAccessCount that returns accessCount? or do you want the member accessCount to be public?

Comment: yeah I hava a `public int getAccessCount(){ retrun accessCount;` but it still have error in `s.accessCount()`

Answer (score 0):

You may use static [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) class type variable and increment it when you are retrivig the instance:

```
public class ExampleSingleton {
    private static AtomicInteger accessCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public static int getAccessCount() {
        return accessCounter.get();
    }
    private static ExampleSingleton instance = new ExampleSingleton();
    private ExampleSingleton() {
        System.out.println("I, the ExampleSingleton, am being created");
    }
    public static ExampleSingleton getInstance() {
        accessCounter.getAndAdd(1);
        System.out.println("The sole instance of ExampleSingleton is being retrieved");
        return instance;
    }
}
```

```
public class ExampleTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExampleSingleton s = ExampleSingleton.getInstance();
        System.out.println("The ExampleSingleton has been "
                + "accessed via the getInstance() method "
                + s.getAccessCount()
                + " time(s)");
        s = ExampleSingleton.getInstance();
        System.out.println("The ExampleSingleton has been "
                + "accessed via the getInstance() method "
                + s.getAccessCount()
                + " time(s)");
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean I should use two static variable to count? then how could I call the instance? Could you please show me?

Comment: @chuang, check the answer, no you need only one AtomicInteger variable

Answer (score 0):

This block of code should be placed inside the `ExampleSingleton` class, and `incrementCounter()` should then be called from `getInstance()`.

The `AtomicInteger` is a class that wraps an integer and supports concurrency, so its far safer than using a standard `Integer` or `Long`. The variable itself is `private static`, so that it's read-only and exists with the singleton class versus the singleton instance.

```
private static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);


public Integer getCount() {
    return counter.get();
}
/**
 * @return the new counter
 */
private Integer incremenetCounter() {
    return counter.incrementAndGet();
}
```

Comment: oh yeah I got it. Thanks